# Performance of SQL Server vs number of databases

Tags: sql-server

Does the number of databases on a SQL Server installation affect performance ?

Lets say I have a multi-tenant application, I have the option of creating a database per tenant or having management table based client table separation or configuration based client table separation.

For 10 clients who are accessing the application, the number of queries are going to be the same regardless of whether I have 10 separate databases or one database.

So does it matter or is there a benefit implementing this one way or the other ?

Comment: check out this links:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61212/at-what-point-does-one-database-per-client-become-unfeasible

Comment: and this one:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-problems-will-i-get-creating-a-database-per-customer